# how to correct the following xml layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have been working on this layout for a long time but I cannot achieve what I really want.

This is my layout :[image: my layout]

What I have tried is :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_competition"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/txt_time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_competition"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/txt_stadium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_time"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_team1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_stadium"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_team1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="العهد"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_team1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_team2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_stadium"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_team2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/versus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_time"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/final_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/versus"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/point_team1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/versus"
            android:text="\?"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/point_team2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/versus"
            android:text="\?"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name_team1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/livetext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

1. How to set the image name in the middle directly under the picture?
2. How can I make all text size fit on all screens? because the tab layout texts are being changed big and small on another screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put image and image name in a LinearView(vertical) and align both of them as center.

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="left">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/image_team1"
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/txt_stadium"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/name_team1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="العهد"
           android:textSize="14dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/image_team1"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
           android:textAlignment="center"/>

   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/image_team2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/txt_stadium"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/name_team2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_above="@+id/view1"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
           android:textSize="14dp"
           android:textAlignment="center"
           android:text="العهد"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Font size won't change as screen changes if you use sp as its unit. Try using a ScrollView with TableLayout

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmad it works ! just more one question if u don't mind.
I want all texts above the images to be on the right of the screen because it's an arabic app so i don't want to show any textview above the images on the left..i want them all on the right

Comment: Yeah it works but i changed  android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" to "center"

Comment: Sorry Ahmad i tested it now the first linear layout  is working perfectly but the second linear layout is overriding the first one !
How can i move the second linear layout to the right of the screen ?

Comment: Put both the linear layouts in another horizontal layout whose layout width is set to match parent. Then set the layout gravity of the second layout to right. Also below is the code to make text above right aligned.

Comment: Okay thank u alot Dear ! 
I have rated u up.
Nice work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for the updated question on the comments

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_competition"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:text="العهد"/>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/txt_time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_competition"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="العهد"
    android:textColor="#666666"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/txt_stadium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_time"
    android:text="العهد"
    android:textColor="#666666"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"/>
```

Comment: thanks also this script worked perfectly !
But i am wondering how can i show under the view (_____) the player who scored the goal with the football icon.
I should  use listview or what

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: i would like to ask if u can pass your email or your facebook account so we can discuss about some codes